# Help with invocable apex method for process builder

Tags: apex, process-builder, class

Create apex class that can be lunched from Process Builder (for Account).
Apex class should make next logic: When new Account is created, create new Task object with Subject “Negotiations with {Account.Name}”, link created Account with this Task.

```
public with sharing class AccountProcessBilder {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void createTask(){
        Task newTask = new Task();
        newTask.Subject = 'Negotiations with ' + Account.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! It looks like you have a good start on a class to suite your requirements. What is the problem you're facing? If you're getting an error message, you should include the full text of the error. You can [edit] your question to add these details.

Comment: i dont know how get Account.Id and use him in newTask.Subject(( i need add account.Id in picklist ( api name = WhatId)! next my step, i need newTask.subject = Account..name

Comment: Does [this question about a similar issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176383/how-do-i-pass-a-case-to-an-apex-class-from-process-builder) help answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@InvocableVariable`, the first example is perfectly suitable for your problem ([link to docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm)). You'll need to create request class, set it as List to method params and left return type as void. Code example is listed below:

```
public with sharing class AccountProcessBilder {
    public class requestObject {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true label='Account ID')
        public Id accountId;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true label='Account Name')
        public String accountName;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Create Task')
    public static void createTask(List<requestObject> requests) {
        List<Task> toInsert = new List<Task>();
        
        for (requestObject request_i : requests) {
            toInsert.add(new Task(WhatId = request_i.accountId, Subject = 'Negotiations with ' + request_i.accountName));
        }
        
        insert toInsert;       
    }
}
```